# Class member function

Tags: python, class, memory

Say I have some class, with a member function that is not used too often, but whose definition is quite lengthy

```
class foo:
    # ...
    fn():
        print('This function is called rarely but its definition is quite lengthy')
    # ...
```

At some point in may program I want to create millions of instances of class foo, and I want this to take as little space in memory as possible. Is the lengthy function fn somehow also copied a million times? In this case it would be better to define an external function which I give an instance as input. If it is not copied a milion times, I would rather keep it as a member function.

Comment: note that your function definition needs the `self` argument or the `@staticmethod` decorator

Comment: It also needs a "def"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods declared at the class level are shared across all instances, just like class variables, so you don't have to worry about methods taking more memory when more instances are instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

An instance method is in fact a member of the class. When the Python interpretor sees a construct like `obj.method(params, ...)`, it (more or less) translates it as `(obj.__class__).method(obj, params, ...)`. It looks for a `method` member in the class of `obj` and calls it after prepending the (reference to) the object itself.

TL/DR: the methods are not copied in instance objects, so you can safely keep you lengthy function as a method.